# onClick in reactjs not showing items

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have to  show a list of defaultValues in the search list and when I click on any of those item then it should take me to that item's component but it's not going anywhere. It's only happening with the defaultValues because as soon as I start typing, then if I click on any search result then it takes me to the desired component. what is wrong with my code?

here's the code

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
const [showDefaultValues, setShowDefaultValues] = useState(false);
const [defaultValues] = useState({
    Mumbai: true
  }); 

 {!search.length && showDefaultValues ? (
            <div className="result-box">
              {data
                .filter((item, idx) => defaultValues[item.district])
                .map((dist, idx) => (
                  <div
                    key={idx}
                    className="search-result"
                    onClick={() => {
                      
                      onResultClick(dist.district);
                    }}
                  >
                    {highlightedText(dist.district, search)}
                    
                  </div>
                ))}
            </div>
          ) : null}
```

Comment: Hmmmm, lets start off by removing `onResultClick(food.foodItem);` and try doing `onClick={() => console.log('test')}`

Comment: If it works, then the function is not getting called and it's probably not passed to the component.The button does work, but the function is not being executed.

Comment: it didn't print anything on the console when I ran the test

Comment: Can you make a quick codesandbox demo of this ? so it will be easier for someone to debug and help.

Comment: ok sure, I will

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-sun-xuxq6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ok will look into this

Comment: it should right or else why would the defaultValues be show!! but the onClick is not working there

Comment: By looking at your sandbox, i found that your onBlur event on the result input causing this issue. If i'm not wrong, its line 48 at your search.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the codes at components/search/search.js line 39 to 49

```
<input
   placeholder="Search for a District..."
   type="text"
   className="search-input"
   value={search}
   onChange={onSearchInputChange}
   onFocus={() => {
      toggleDefaultValues(true);
   }}
   onBlur={onBlurInput}
/>
```

To

```
<input
   placeholder="Search for a District..."
   type="text"
   className="search-input"
   value={search}
   onChange={onSearchInputChange}
   onFocus={() => {
      toggleDefaultValues(true);
   }}
/>
```

Or simply remove line 48

To compensate this, you can add below inside your useEffect (similar to componentDidMount)

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleInputClickOutside);
```

add function handleInputClickOutside to set the state to false/hide

Comment: blur will be triggered before onClick on the execution. So It's ignoring the click event.

Comment: but now it doesn't removes the search list if I click outside of that list.

Comment: You can use "addEventListener()" to hide the results.

Comment: can you please show it? i've been stuck here for quite a while

Comment: I did but it's quite not working. have a look here https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-banzai-1di30

Comment: I forked and added the codes for you https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-shape-fmlp8

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to implement the onClick logic on the default search result items and that's why the search results work fine, while the default search items do not.

Check this link to the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-fermi-expot?file=/src/App.js).

All i did was invoke the same onResultClick function onClick of 'District' component.

```
<div
        className="dist"
        onClick={() => {
          this.props.onResultClick(item.district);
        }}
      >
...
</div>
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: hmmmmmm if this works, how come i cannot see `console.log("item", dist); ` ? curious to know. Check the search component, and you'll know what im referring too.

Comment: That's probably because i removed the console log from the onClick of the District component, as I have shown in the snippet above.

Comment: @reactRookie does this help ?

Comment: Umm, can you please elaborate what's not working @reactRookie . In the codesandbox I have provided a link to; clicking on the default list items take you to there individual component. Correct me if I am wrong, but that's what i got from the question

Comment: no it didn't take me to the desired component. if i click on the default value then it's not doing anything